# Rigidity or Bodies with Triangular Shapes of Faces

Tags: forces, rigid-body-dynamics, stress-strain

Originally I read an answer on Quora wherein the author showed that by using magnets he made different shapes.

Squares were easily deformed, so we're other shapes with square faces such as cubes however shapes with Triangular faves such as a triangle itself or a tetrahedron were very rigid.

I'm unable to link the answer directly so I'll link the question itself

https://www.quora.com/Is-a-triangle-stronger-than-a-square

The answer by Philip Lloyd consists of images of the figures I'm talking about.

https://www.quora.com/profile/Philip-Lloyd-2

What is the reason for this difference in strength and how can we show this mathematically that is easier to deform one over the other. It is relatively intuitive however I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is geometry.

For the other shapes, you can have the same length members, while having a *connected range* of angles between the members where all the lengths still touch.  You can move the shape between these angles fairly freely, especially in the case of magnets where each magnet is essentially a pinned joint.

With a triangle, or triangle based geometries, you cannot change the angle between each member without also changing the length of at least one member.  With rigid bodies, this does not happen, so a triangular shape makes a stable structure which cannot be adjusted without deformation; even if the joints are only pinned members.

Comment: Yes just the logic I was looking for thanks a lot